# How do you theme an autocomplete dropdown

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to theme an autocomplete dropdown from a textfield. In this case the autocomplete is provided from the finder module.

I need to theme it beyond just simply adding css. Ideally I'd like a theme function to override or a template file but I can't find one.

I have tried using the theme function which is provided by the finder module, however all that does is theme the resulting page, not the autocomplete drop down.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Just to confirm, is it the autocomplete widget provided by core or one that the Finder module provides?

Comment: Ideally the one that finder provides, However if there's a way to do it with core then I'll just code it  with the normal autocomplete field. I don't need half of the gui features of finder anyway.

Comment: Can you be more specific about in what ways you want to theme the dropdown? Can you give an example of what you expect to see as the end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To theme the Drupal 7 finder autocomplete dropdown take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEBsNTR-2lY). Generally you write PHP into the 'Rewrite' settings on the advanced options of the finder. I would avoid using the theme() function, it might be obsolete.

To theme the Drupal 6 finder version, you may find [this article](http://web2make.com/content/drupal-autocomplete-node-title-and-image) helpful. It uses theme functions.